# AppLocalizations without context in flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to use

```
AppLocalization.of(context)!.home,
```

without context. I'm using this in my class model where there's no context.
Here's my class:

```
class MenuItems {

 static const home = MenuItem('Home',Icons.home);
 static const frequentQuestion = MenuItem('Frequent Questions', Icons.question_answer);

 static const all = <MenuItem>[
      home,
      frequentQuestion,
 ];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this issue by
declaring variable global like

```
BuildContext? kAppcontext
```

Then I initialized in main.dart under build
now wherever I need it I used it as

```
 static const frequentQuestion = MenuItem(AppLocalizations.of(kAppcontext!)!.home,Icons.home);
```